# Platform / extranet suggestions for capturing data from external sales agents

Tags: forms, sharepoint, cloud, workflow, extranet

I'm looking for suggestions for a tool/platform that can help in capturing form and file attachment data from external sales agents. I currently use Google Forms and a plugin to enable sending email notifications to specific contacts, but the hope is to create something more advanced where people providing the data can login to submit data and make updates to the records. The platform should also enable approval workflows with email notifications to ensure the incoming data meets requirements.

**Here is a description of the desired process:**

- Agent logs in to the platform
- Agent submits data (and optional file attachments) into the system using a form
- Upon submission, the system triggers a review task and sends an email notification to a reviewer
- If the reviewer deems the information invalid/incomplete, they will
  reject it, with comment, and the system will
  automatically send the information back to the agent while copying
  their manager. Record status will be updated automatically.
- If the reviewer deems the information invalid, they will approve it, with or without
  comment, and the system will automatically send the information back to the agent while copying
  their manager and project administrator. Record status will be updated automatically.

**Additional requirements:**

- Contacts for email notifications will vary by agent and they should be determined by identification items on the user/agent profile
- Agents need to be able to update records but a new review task will be triggered once an update is submitted
- The system should have functionality for searching the record fields
- An agent should see their own data and data submitted by others in the same agency, but not the data submitted by agents outside their agency
- I should be able to see the full list of submissions and version history of the records
- Approximate scale: 100-150 agencies, 1000-1500 agents

So far, I've thought of using a list within SharePoint Online combined with Microsoft Flow, but I'm not sure it would enable all the desired functionality. I'd be interested in your thoughts about that setup as well as others that you think could work and/or have found successful. Even if your solution does not tick all the boxes, I'd be interested to know about it.

Thanks a lot for your help!

JP